# Profiling with Intel Vtune Amplifier

Tags: directshow, intel, intel-vtune

I have create one filter dll using some static libs and this dll is used in graph studio and it's running fine. But I have to do profiling of my dll, so I have started graph studio then vtune. In vtune project property I have attached it to process and successfully generated the Profile report. But I only able to see assembly of my code not c/c++ source of my code. How to see the source code of my dll in Vtune?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify where to search for Symbol files.

Here is a good documentation https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/resolving-symbol-references-after-data-collection

Comment: I have already did this because of .pdb file I am able to see function names. But I am not able to see my source code in c/c++. How to locate source code?

Comment: You might try to specify "Source Search" folders as well. Open results windows and you'll see `Source Search` button on the `Collection Log` page. Do `Re-resolve` after that.